# Opengl loading matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix

If I want to build translate matrix in OpenGl does i have to do:

```
float f[16] =
{
    1,0,0,1,
    0,1,0,2,
    0,0,1,3,
    0,0,0,1
};

glLoadMatrixf(f);
```

or

```
float f[16] =
{
    1,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    1,2,3,1
};

glLoadMatrixf(f);
```

Row-column or column-row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one. OpenGL indexes its matrices in the following order

```
0 4 8 c
1 5 9 d
2 6 a e
3 7 b f
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872049(v=vs.85).aspx
scroll down a little and they show you the exact layout for the array vs the matrix.